ingress-nginx-controller didn't update stream ip when pod ip changed
Up until now, updating the image of a pod didn't break anything. This last time however, the pod itself got a new ip in the cluster and my service became unreachable (502 Bad Gateway). I debugged every step of the request to find the problem, from browser to container. On the logs of the ingress-nginx-controller pod, I found this suspicious line:
2024/05/15 15:36:27 [error] 7032#7032: *230837456 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: <client-ip>, server: mysubdomain.mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.244.0.24:<port>/", host: "mysubdomain.mydomain.com"

The upstream IP (10.244.0.24) corresponds to the old pod IP, before my update. After rolling out the update, the pod IP became 10.244.0.61.
It's the first time it happens to my cluster. Maybe normally the pod IP doesn't change with updates or maybe ingress-nginx-controller gets updated when an upstream ip changes. Or maybe something else, I don't know how it works, but I see it does. Up until now.
Restarting the node didn't solve it. The ingress-nginx-controller pod won't start. It keeps restarting.
Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge. Deeply appreciated.

It is more likely that the pod’s ip address will change base from its lifecycle though we cannot tell when it will happen. From the link shared under “Pod lifetime” It was mentioned that “Pods do not, by themselves, self-heal.” That is why if something happens to a pod it will be deleted or destroyed and replaced with a new one and that is the time the IP address will change.
Sharing also with you this link wherein the solution is to change the IP address since nginx cached IP address are no longer exist.
Also, if you consider, you can also connect your nginx ingress controller to a service cluster IP address that is associated with your Pods. The Cluster IP address assigned to a service is generally static for the duration of the service. Once allocated, it remains the same as long as the service is active
